# pip install --upgrade pip isnt upgrading pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to upgrade pip on **Centos 7**. I `pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)` installed.

When I run `pip install --upgrade pip --user` I get the following output:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-8.1.2
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

### What I've tried

I've tried the following, which have all resulted in the same output and result as above:

- `pip install --upgrade pip --user`
- `pip install -U pip --user  --ignore-installed`
- `pip install -U pip --user  --ignore-installed --no-cache-dir`
- `sudo yum update pip` which returns

```
No Match for argument: pip
No package pip available.
No packages marked for update
```

- `sudo yum update python-pip` which returns `No packages marked for update`

### Observations

`python -m pip --version` outputs:

`pip 19.3.1 from /home/deploy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

`pip --version` outputs:

`pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`

Comment: Sorry for a strange question: aren't you running Manjaro Linux?

Comment: Do not upgrade the system pip with the system pip itself.  It should only be modified using your OS package manager. If you want to use a newer pip, that's fine, just put a newer one earlier in $PATH - but leave the system pip alone!

Comment: Why would I want to leave the system pip alone, when it is clearly out of date?

Comment: Because your distribution (Centos) carefully chose and tested everything to be compatible.  If you just want to turn off the system pip's nag, set `disable_pip_version_check = true` in your pip config file.  If you want to use the newest pip avail, install it for your user only.

Comment: Just a remark: The pip package in CentOS is called python-pip, you should use `sudo yum update python-pip` instead of `sudo yum update pip`

Comment: @wim makes some good points. On top of what they said, I _strongly_ recommend using some sort of environment management tool.

Comment: I've tried using `yum` (see above). What do you mean by "environment management tool". I'm using Ansible. But that isnt related to these pip issues.

Comment: [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) is an excellent choice (and example) re: environment management tools -- you don't just get a virtualenv where you choose your Python packages, you also choose your Python interpreter and your native libraries, and can ask for things like "for only this one project, I want my Python interpreter compiled against openssl 1.0.x instead of 1.1.x", or "compiled with gcc 7 instead of gcc 8", or what-have-you.

Comment: ...with a conventional distro like CentOS, you can only have one version of each package installed system-wide; whereas a good environment-management system lets you have as many environments with completely different (and potentially mutually-incompatible) sets of installed software as you want, with none of them conflicting with each other or running any risk of breaking your larger OS. Think of it like a virtualenv, but for every piece of software you have installed, not just for Python libraries.

Comment: Using nix to upgrade pip sounds like overkill. This should be something very simple, and shouldnt require a new package manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your PATH to include `/home/deploy/.local/lib/python2.7/bin` before `/usr/lib/python2.7/bin` if you want `pip` to resolve to the same location as `python`. Otherwise, `python -m pip` is the more proper usage pattern

Otherwise, you're looking at two completely separate python installations and pip is indeed upgraded in one of them

Note: Python2 is end of life, so probably best to remove the one in your home folder, anyway, and switch to using something like Pipenv or pyenv